# Please Help: Nvidia Drivers on Optimus Laptop Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: nvidia

so I tried to install the vulkan driver a couple of days ago, but it did not work so I tried restoring my system by first uninstalling the vulkan driver, then purging everything nvidia, then installing nvidia-352 and nvidia-prime. But now GL doesn't work so I can only use xfce (which I am writing this on). In my Xorg.0.log (http://paste.ubuntu.com/15101909/) I have this line: (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found). So now all GL programs won't run. Currently I am using the 355 driver because some guy on the forum said it might work but it didn't fix the problem. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Notes: To be clear, I am no longer intending to install the beta vulkan driver. I have a muxless laptop so no, I can not disable the intel graphx card. And finally my graphics card is a GTX 960M.

EDIT:
Here is the output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
http://pastebin.com/1aLhr4Th

EDIT 2:
Here is the output of dkms status

```
    bbswitch, 0.7, 4.2.0-23-generic, x86_64: installed
    bbswitch, 0.7, 4.2.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
    bbswitch, 0.7, 4.2.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
```

EDIT 3:
Here is what happens when I try to run a GL application:

```
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

EDIT 4:

```
 prime-select query
```

returns

```
 nvidia
```

EDIT 5:

```
 glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

returns

```
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

EDIT 6:

```
    grep i915 /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

returns nothing

EDIT 7:

```
 lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

returns

```
     00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th           Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:185d]
     00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
     --
     01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce   GTX 960M] [10de:139b] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:185d]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

EDIT 8:

```
    modinfo i915 | grep -i 0416
```

returns

```
    alias:          pci:v00008086d00000416sv*sd*bc03sc*i*
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Also please add output of `dkms status`.

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with the Intel adapter. Post the second output just here. There is no need to use pastebin.

Comment: You have still `bbswitch` from the other driver. But you do not have the Nvidia driver. That's the problem.

Comment: Please post output of `prime-select query`

Comment: And also `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

Comment: OK. Something is wrong with Intel. Post output of `grep i915 /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe i915`

Comment: Is that supposed to return anything, because it doesn't

Comment: Good. What does `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` show now?

Comment: Now please add output of `modinfo i915 | grep -i 0416`

Comment: This is mysterious.  I see what is the problem, but I do not know how to fix it. The dual graphics won't work without `i915` module. It is not blacklisted and it supports the adapter, but it does not start for some reason.

Comment: I do not care about dual graphics, I just want to use the GTX 960M

Comment: It does not matter. Either way the Nvidia adapter outputs through the Intel. It will be much easier to re-install, than to search for some configs that are broken somehow.

Comment: oh, do you know if there is a way to reinstall w/o losing programs and configurations etc.?

Comment: Is it possible to reinstall everything graphics related?  Like X, nvidia drivers, etc.

Comment: Also what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully uninstall the drivers, you installed before and then install them again.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo apt-get purge bbswitch-dkms
sudo dkms remove bbswitch/0.7 --all
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

then reboot.

Comment: Oh wait nvm, I think I found the problem, rebooting now

Comment: ya I still have the same problem, all the GL programs return the same error.